# I cant use Schedule in python

Tags: python, schedule

In the schedule docs, i copy the same function

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

but it isnt working

```
    schedule.every().seconds.do(job)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'schedule' has no attribute 'every' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 1):

What did you name your source code file? If you named it `schedule.py`, please consider changing it to another filename like:

```
python3 scheduling_app.py
```

And not:

```
python3 schedule.py
```